# Loop for, condition 2, doesn't comply

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I'm a student with limited JavaScript knowledge (first year) and need help with Project Euler #2.

```js
var arr = [1, 2];
var total = 2;
var x = 0;
var y = 1;
for (var i; total < 4000000; x++, y++) {
  i = arr[x] + arr[y];
  arr.push(i);
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    total += i
  }
}
console.log(total);
```

My loop is supposed to stop when the total is less than 4,000,000 but for some reason, the total is 4,613,732.

Comment: Well you don't increment your `total` by 1 per iteration, you add `i` to it. It never meets 4000000 exactly.

Comment: You might try stepping through your code in a debugger to see what it is doing to reach the value that it does. Alternatively, add `console.log(total)` inside the for loop to check what is happening.

Comment: @Bergi Sorry, I meant that my total should be less than 4,000,000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem statement from [Project Euler #2](https://projecteuler.net/problem=2):

> Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the
>   previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will
>   be:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
>
> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not
>   exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

You have misinterpreted "four million" to be the upper bound on the *sum*, whereas it is actually the upper bound on the individual numbers.

Therefore the loop condition should be `i <= 4000000`; but that's not all - you need to rearrange the conditions because `i` is set *inside* the loop, so the condition will not catch the last number added.

```
for (var i;; x++, y++) {
  i = arr[x] + arr[y];
  if (i > 4000000) break; // move condition to here
  arr.push(i);
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    total += i
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was about to comment on my stupidity but you beat me to it. Here is my final code which gave the correct answer:                                      
`for (var i = 0; i < 4000000; x++, y++) {
  i = arr[x] + arr[y];
  arr.push(i);
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    total += i;
  }
}`

Comment: @SindreEiklid that code might have worked for this particular case but it will not work for a general value in place of 4000000. Can you see why?

Comment: I tried a few different values which gave the right answer. Is it because the last value might be added to the total?

Comment: @SindreEiklid yes. For example, try 7 instead of 4000000. The expected answer would be 2, but the actual result is 10, because it also adds the 8 when `i = 5` before exiting. In fact this will happen for any value between a pair of Fib numbers if the first one is odd and the second one even.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is 'not' doing anything unusual, the for is running until total is more than 4,000,000.

For example if i were to add 20 each time my for loops to my total and i check every time if my total is more than 50, it will run until i get 60.
not less than 60 and it will never be 50 because im adding 20 each for.

since the loop is adding 20 for each loop, in your case is the same, just add an if inside your loop, checking if the total is bigger than what you actually want, if it is, break it and do not add the value that will make it go over your desired value.

So:

> My loop is supposed to stop after total is equal to 4,000,000 but for
>   some reason, the total is 4,613,732.

what you are adding maybe just is never going to make total exactly 4,000,000 and if it is then just change your condition to `total <= 4000000;` instead of `total < 4000000;`

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to think my way through recursive functions when they're expressed using functional style

```js
const projectEuler2 = (limit = 0, sum = 0, a = 0, b = 1) =>
  a > limit
    ? sum
    : projectEuler2
        ( limit
        , a & 1 ? sum : sum + a
        , b
        , a + b
        ) 
    
console.log (projectEuler2 (4e6))
// 4613732
```